# add_action to specific page type or post ID on WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the following WooCommerce shortcode to output product data from a certain category on a page:

`<?php echo do_shortcode('[products category="'. $category .'" columns="1"]'); ?>`

By default, this code does not include the product short description, but I can add the following to the functions.php file to enable the short description:

`add_action('wc_single_excerpt' , 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 10 , 2);`

However, this will then output the product short description on every single WooCommerce product loop which I don't want to do.

My question is, how can I ONLY output the product short description i.e. the add_action on a page that has an ID of 123 for example?

Answer (score 1):

call this function `woocommerce_template_single_excerpt` conditionally:

```
add_action('wc_single_excerpt' , function() {
   // if it's in a loop
   if( get_the_ID() == 123 ) {
     woocommerce_template_single_excerpt();
   }
}, 10 , 2);
```

let me know if it answers your question